# What is wrong with my .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^random-number-generator$ random-number-generator.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^calculator$ calculator.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^currency-converter$ currency-converter.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^youtube-statistics$ youtube-statistics.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^check-website-status$ /check-website-status.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^your-ip-address$ your-ip-address.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ contact-us.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://themegahouse.com/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://themegahouse.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.themegahouse.com/.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.themegahouse.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://themegahouse.com/restricted [R,NC,L]

ErrorDocument 401 /not-found.php 
ErrorDocument 403 /restricted.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
```

When I visit the root of my site in a browser, I am getting Forbidden?

I am sure it is this file because when I remove it, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow empty referers, too. Put the following rule right *before* your other rewriteconds:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
```

Comment: I am still getting Forbidden?

Comment: Try again; forgot to remove the `[NC]` when doing copy&paste.